# Why do object responses undefined?

Tags: javascript, vk

```
<script src="http://vkontakte.ru/js/api/openapi.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<div id="login_button" onclick="VK.Auth.login(getit);"></div>
<script language="javascript">
VK.init({
    apiId: 2903251
});
function getit(response) {
    if (response.session) {
        var id = response.session.mid;
    }
    VK.Api.call('users.get', {uids: id, fields: 'sex,photo_big'}, function(r) {
        if(r.response) {
            alert(r.response.sex);
            console.log(r.response);
        }
    });
}
VK.UI.button('login_button');
</script>
```

Why does `alert(r.response.sex)` display undefined, but everything is OK with console logs?

Comment: Paste what's actually showing up in the console log (e.g. the exact contents of r.response).

Comment: [
Object
first_name: "Георгий"
last_name: "Липартелиани"
photo_big: "http://cs5221.userapi.com/u7817320/a_7b0f9a48.jpg"
sex: 2
uid: 7817320
__proto__: Object

Comment: @GeorgyLiparteliani — That looks hideously broken. Are you transcribing it manually? What software are you console.logging it with?

Comment: Google chrome.Why is it broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. The solution:
r.response[0].sex